# Deleting namespace in Socket IO

Tags: node.js, namespaces, socket.io, typescript

This question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400595/socket-io-how-do-i-remove-a-namespace), but I've implemented the answer and the problem has persisted.

I'm working in typescript and I have a Room class that encapsulates a namespace (among other things), and a RoomManager class that maintains a list of rooms. I recently added functionality where a room is removed from the list of rooms upon the user count reaching 0. Inside the room, it sets the namespace field to null. The room is removed from the manager. However, when I create the namespace again later, I run into problems that I've found indicative of multiple namespaces with the same name.

The linked answer stated that removing the namespace from the array would delete it, but something about my situation is preventing the namespace from disappearing. I don't know a lot about garbage collecting, but that's my uneducated guess at where the problem lies. I'd be happy to post some code and more specifics if needed.

**EDIT**: adding some code:
Room constructor:

```
constructor(namespace: SocketIO.Namespace, manager: roomManager) {
    this.users = new Array();
    this.manager = manager;
    var room = this;
    namespace.on('connection', function(socket) {
    //socket events that use the room reference to the object to complete tasks
    }
    this.namespace = namespace;
}
```

Function that removes the namespace and one that removes the room from array:

```
removeUser(user: User){
    var index: number = this.users.indexOf(user);
    if (index > -1){
        this.users.splice(index, 1);
    }
    if (this.users.length < 1){
        this.namespace = null;
        this.manager.removeRoom(this);
    }
}

removeRoom(room: Room){
    var index: number = this.rooms.indexOf(room);
    if (index > -1){
        this.rooms.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: So far you've explained your problem well, however, without code we will be unable to provide any assistance that would be useful to future visitors (all we could do is speculate/guess at what the problem might be.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, updated

Comment: what exactly is `user`? an object? a string? are you positive it is properly being removed from the array?

Comment: Sorry, User is another class. It encapsulates a socket and a username.

Comment: then, is it the exact same object as the one stored in the array? Not just same structure, but literally the same object? two different objects, even if identical, are not equal. for example, `var x = {foo:1}, y = {foo:1}; x===y; // false`

Comment: Sorry, which array? I have two: room manager has an array of rooms, room has an array of users .

Comment: either or i guess, they'd likely both be having the same problem.

Comment: My arrays should be storing references to the same object, I use array.push (object) to add objects to them

Comment: And your storing that object, and then passing it directly back to removeRoom or removeUser, correct?

Comment: Yes, the room object sends itself (this) the room manager, which the room manager removes from the array. My debugging confirms it is correctly removed, it doesn't show up when I print the array

Comment: I'm all out of ideas then. The problem is likely a minor logic error somewhere other than in the code presented. can you expand on the "problems" that you are seeing when you try to create a namespace that you previously removed?

Comment: I'll post more code in a second. Chat messages sent are emitted 2 times, which has happened everytime I have a client connected to 2 namespaces of the same name

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a client-side issue? are there any symptoms of the problem server-side, or are you only seeing it client-side.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I'm fairly sure my problem is that i have 2 namespaces with the same name. The code was working fine before I added the functionality where rooms with 0 users were removed. After I added that functionality, the multiple emissions of messages started if I created a namespace, then exited (removing it from the array), then joined again (creating it again). Before, exiting a room wouldn't remove it, so joining again wouldn't recreate a namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who has this specific problem, I found the answer. I misunderstood the linked question: I didn't realize the array that was being discussed was located in the Server object in SocketIO, not an outside array. Furthermore, at the time of this post, Typescript's SocketIO .d.ts file doesn't define the nsps array that exists in the Server object. I solved the problem by adding the property to my .d.ts file and following the deletion instructions outlined in the linked question.